# Post request to Firebase push notifications nothing happens

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

//Iam trying to do a post request for push notification, but nothing happens..

//The interface

```
    interface RestInterface {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: key)
    @POST("fcm/send")
    fun sendingNotification(@Body body: NotificationBody?): Call<ResponseBody?>?
 }
```

//NotificationBody

```
class NotificationBody(data: Data, to: String) {
    @SerializedName("notification")
    private val data: Data

    @SerializedName("to")
    private val to: String

    init {
        this.data = data
        this.to = to
    }
}
```

//Data class

```
 class Data
 (@field:SerializedName("title")
 private val title: String,
 @field:SerializedName("content")
 private val content: String)
```

//Retrofit Request

```
 fun sentNotification() {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()

            .baseUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

    var title = "My Title";
    var content = "My message";
    var to = deviceId

    var data = Data(title, content);
    var body = NotificationBody(data, to);

    val service = retrofit.create(RestInterface::class.java)

    val response = service.sendingNotification(body)
```

i implemented response code but get a a lot of error. Remind, iam with kotlin not java.

```
 response.enqueue( Callback<ResponseBody>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call, 
   retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
         Log.d("kkkk","done");
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call, 
    Throwable t) {

     }
 })

}
```

//Whats wrong with above request setup ?
//if is sent the message with postman The notification is showing on the phone, so the onMessageReceived settings are ok

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828430/how-to-send-fcm-notification-from-android-using-retrofit

Comment: I did!, but the strange thing is no errors but also no Notification

Comment: what is the response code/message you're getting from api

Comment: i get nothing back, dont have experience with retrofit and dont know how to get respons from the request. My idea is that after service.sendingNotification(body) i have to setup the response code/message. But i dont know how

Comment: But can you judge my code, i dont see why its not working.

Comment: i implemented response code but get a a lot of error. Remind, iam with kotlin not java. See my edited code